# Counter System for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, counter

how can i make a counter to be used in addressing issues. (sample output: Issue 001). I need to save the current value of the counter(001) in the device so that when there is another issue to be sent by the app i will increment the current value of the counter.
Don't know where to start.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Start by searching Google. Did you do any research for this before asking your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `NSUserDefaults`

get and store the value

```
NSInteger count = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"count"] integerValue];
count++;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:count] forKey:@"count"];
```

Comment: after saving, how will i get the value of count? @YuviGr

Comment: the first line of code gets the count from the NSUserDefaults

Comment: the last line of code saves the count value to NSUserDefaults